# Why sql query is not return data if I search exact string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table called with column name `gift_code` which type is `varchar(20)` and now it's contain `GREATDAY` string data.

Now why I a run following sql query it's return 0. I don't understand why  it's happening ?!

The `string` can contain Uppercase or Lowercase characters. I want to search exact match

```
$checkPromo     = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM gift_card WHERE gift_code = 'GREATDAY'   ");
echo $numPromo   = mysqli_num_rows($checkPromo);
```

I used `BINARY` keyword but not working :(

Comment: You could also try `WHERE gift_code LIKE '%GREATDAY%'` ... if that also returns nothing, then your probably have a PHP problem of some kind.

Comment: Well, Now its returning but not case sensitive ? 'GREATDAY' AND 'GREATDay' both is true now.

Comment: It's should be case sensitive search

Comment: I should use BINARY now :)

Comment: I think you have single quotes in your values `'GREATDAY'` and `'GREATDay'`. Change them to `GREATDAY` and `GREATDay` and try again

Answer (score 2):

`COLLATE utf8_general_cs` is what matters. When the column's collate is set to this, the case-sensitive will work. if your column collate is `utf8_general_ci` this will ignore the case sensitiveness while querying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try trimming your data in the database , it can contain various unnecessary characters which make the string match return nothing , 
Or, 
You can select all data from the database and trim them and compare with "GREATDAY" if its not working you can echo it and go to page source to see if there are any br or p tags ,